# Django code executed by post_save signal happens within atomic transaction

Tags: django, transactions, signals, django-1.6

Upgrading to Django 1.6 has introduced a tricky problem into my code: database operations that are triggered by a `post_save` signal are getting contained within the
    `with transaction.atomic():`
block of Django's `get_or_create()`.

The impact for me is that custom sql (unmanaged) isn't getting committed to the db in time.

Is there a different signal that I can use that gets sent *after*  `obj.save()` exits its atomic block?

Or have I diagnosed this wrong?

Comment: apparently this has been a [ticket/discussion for years now](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14051)... which led me to [this  module](https://github.com/aaugustin/django-transaction-signals) which adds transaction-level signals.

Comment: but to clarify the question: is the post_save signal getting fired from within that atomic block, causing all code run by that signal to be executed with autocommit turned off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django's `get_or_create()` executes its `save()` in an atomic block, and signals fired post_save are nested within that atomic block.

My workaround was to override the native `get_or_create()` with my own version in a custom manager, without the `transaction.atomic()` block.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I came across this today.

Django >=1.9 supports [transaction.on_commit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.on_commit) hooks.

Here's how my resulting code came out, and appears to behave as expected:

```py
from django.db import transaction

def my_post_save_hook(sender, instance):
    transaction.on_commit(
        lambda: do_the_thing()
    )

post_save.connect(my_post_save_hook, sender=MyModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

for the signal to function properly you need out of the atomic transaction, because in the midst of shooting transsaccion signal without the commmit in the database.